# How to run remote seamless apps on MacOS using remote VM running on W11 Pro x64 - can this be done using VirtualBox/QEMU using local network RDP?

Tags: virtualbox, remote-desktop, qemu, remoteapp, seamless

I'm currently using Parallels to access remote apps on a MacBook Air M2 and want to shift into running VMs on a Windows 11 Pro machine that pack a lot more punch. Can anyone recommend the best approach? I don't have Windows server OS so RDP remote apps may not be possible (I could be wrong though???)

I've run local VMs in the past using VMware/Vbox in seamless (or unity mode as it's called on VMware). Just wondering the best approach to do this but over a network so I can access windows apps on MacOS using seamless mode.

I've also thought about Winapps (got this running years ago on Linux but it was quite glitchy).

The goal is to run these apps as if they were native on MacOS to access certain files stored on my Mac. I'd be using this only ever on the local network using a 2.5GB ethernet connection.

Thank you in advance!